# Adding a dynamic function to an object

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm trying to get this to work, but it doesn't:

```
var i; 

i.test = function() { 
    alert("hello"); 
}

i.test();
```

I expect the code to alert 'hello', but instead, the Firefox error console shows:

```
missing } in XML expression
alert("hello"); 
---------------^
```

How do I fix this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` isn't assigned to anything so it's not an object. It is, in fact, pointing to the global `undefined` object which happens to be read-only in Firefox (as it should be). You need:

```
var i = {}; //init to empty object
```

then all will be fine.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = {};
i.test = function() { 
    alert("hello"); 
};
```

You had two separate issues.  You were not initializing `i` (as noted by slebetman), and you were missing a semi-colon, forcing the interpreter to use semi-colon replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a function to an undefined value, you need to create an actual object:

```
var i = {};
```

Although not required, you should have a semicolon at the end of the statement to avoid ambiguity:

```
i.test = function() { 
  alert("hello"); 
};
```